Scene lighting acting strangely when I change scene
I have been encountering this problem when I use SceneManager to change the scene or restart. where the new scene looks darker and the shadows more prominent even though the values are the same.
See here, I used SceneManager to restart the game after gameover:
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
How it is from the start and has to be
after restarting:
How it gets after restarting
I doubt it has anything to do with my code. So, I tried changing directional light's color, intensity, shadows, etc. But nothing changed. The values are the same in both scenes.
The closest question I found was this:Scene design (color) changes after loading scene. Based on that I went to window>rendering>lightning> environment, made sure Auto generation was unchecked, and clicked generate lightning. Nothing happened. But I'm not quite sure what it's supposed to do.
the lightning setting

Check out environment. iirc, the choices there are per-scene. So if you have made changes to skybox or ambient light or whatever, it'll be there. On another note, does this happen only when loading the scene? e.g. Does the scene opened in-editor standalone produce the same issue?
Auto-generation only applies if you have set things up to use lightmaps (baked light)

Only when I use SceneManager to load the scenes. And when I do the scene looks this way in both the game scene and the editor. I haven't made any unique choices to any scenes, all the settings have the same as I checked.

Can't think of anything else. But until someone else suggests sth, try deleting the Library and regenerating everything. Sometimes artifacts in the Library are corrupted and make for strange behavior.
